# How can I read different history.pushStates on windows.popState in javascript?

Tags: javascript, window, pushstate, popstate

There are two pushStates in my code. I want to read those states separately and run different functions.But whenever the form is not submitted,pushState affiliated with it is not triggered and this error is showing: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null at window.onpopstate (poke.js:18)`
This code is inside the event 'DOMContentLoaded'. How can I read different pushStates on onpopstate?

//code

```
window.onpopstate = function(event){
        if(event.state.name){
            
            getInfo(event.state.get_info,cards,pgHeader,pokeInfo,pokeDiv);
        }else {
            
            showAll(cards,pgHeader,pgParagraph,pokeInfo,pokeDiv);
        };
    };

    all_poke.onclick = ()=>{
        history.pushState(null,null,"/all_pokemons")
        pokeInfo.innerHTML = '';
        showAll(cards,pgHeader,pgParagraph,pokeInfo,pokeDiv);
        return false;
    }
  
    form.onsubmit = function (){
        
        pgParagraph.innerHTML = '';
        var name = searchBox.value;
        history.pushState({name},null,`${name}/info`)
        getInfo(name,cards,pgHeader,pokeInfo,pokeDiv)
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Which line is `poke.js:18`? And what are you `getInfo` and `showAll` functions?

Comment: In the all_poke.onclick event ,its pushing a state having no object as the first param. But in the form.onsubmit event a state is pushed where an object called 'name' is passed. Now when the onclick event is running only, then the getInfo() is generating the error inside the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with the `?.` operator.
This checks if the `name` property exists and returns `undefined` instead of an error if the name is not present.

```
if (event.state?.name) {
```

Alternatively, if you need older browser support or for other reasons, just check if the `state` property is `null`, since that is one of the two options in your code.

```
if (event.state !== null) {
```

Comment: Thanks Emiel. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @Mahbub Nice! Be sure to accept the answer (checkmark top left of answer).